# Why does data appear to go missing when switching from geom_point to geom_line?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, time-series

I have created a large data frame (BEAVOutletWL_merge) that I am trying to produce plots pulling data from the various columns. When I input the following code:

```
BEAVbaro <- ggplot(BEAVOutletWL_merge, aes(x=DateTime,y=BaroPres_kpa)) +
geom_point(size = .01)+
labs(x=NULL, y="BaroPres_kpa") + ylim(98, 103)+
theme()+ggtitle("Beaver Marsh")
BEAVbaro
```

This is the plot that is produced:

[image]

However, when I try to make it a line plot using this code:

```
BEAVbaro <- ggplot(BEAVOutletWL_merge, aes(x=DateTime,y=BaroPres_kpa)) +
geom_line(size = .5)+
labs(x=NULL, y="BaroPres_kpa") + ylim(98, 103)+
theme()+ggtitle("Beaver Marsh")
BEAVbaro
```

This plot is produced:

[image]

The only thing that I have changed is "geom_point" to "geom_line" and the size (for aesthetic purpose) but does anyone know why the large chunk of data between 01/22 and 07/22 suddenly disappears on the line plot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `ggplot` leaves blanks in lines where there are `NA` values, points that are flanked by `NA` values won't show up with `geom_line`.  Example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
dd <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                 y  = c(1, NA, 3, NA, 5, NA, 7, NA, 9, 10))

gg0 <- ggplot(dd, aes(x,y))

plot_grid(gg0 + geom_point(), gg0 + geom_line())
```

[image]

If you're OK with linear interpolation, you can fix this with `na.omit()`:

```r
gg0  %+% na.omit(dd) + geom_line()
```

[image]

It would be interesting but a little more of a challenge than I have time for right now to plot a placeholder (e.g. a short horizontal dash) at the location of every `NA`-flanked data point ..)